# Cannot Reuse the same string (char array) in C

Tags: c

Following code leads to Segmentation Fault when trying to reuse the string.

```
for(i=0;i<input_len;i++){
        char *loc=(char*)calloc(sizeof(char)*2,0);

                int pointer = 0;
        while(pointer<3){
            int local_index = pointer+i;
            sprintf(loc,"%02x",input[local_index]&0xff);    
            strcat(stream_length_string, loc);
            pointer++;
        }
        local_length = strtol(stream_length_string, NULL, 16);
            i=(local_length+8);

        loc[0]= 0;
}
```

I am trying to use the string loc at each iteration but in the 2nd iteration, it gives segmentation fault at the sprintf statement. I guess it is somehow not able to clear the contents of loc and re-fill it.

Comment: Why do you think it might be segfaulting?  What do you get if you write out on paper the values of `pointer` and `local_index` and `i` for every iteration, and consider what memory the code is trying to access as a result?  Segmentation Faults relate to something "unprivileged" (your code) trying to access memory belonging to something else (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault)

Comment: [`calloc(x*2, 0)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/calloc) – what do you think how many bytes that will allocate?

Comment: Re. my earlier comment - I've remembered what I was trying to suggest - "Trace tables": https://www.bouraspage.com/repository/algorithmic-thinking/what-is-a-trace-table

Comment: Is the input_len size of the input[] array? If so, local_index might be exceed it.

Comment: The [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3p.html) tells us: "http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/calloc.3p.html". You do not check if `loc` is `NULL`.

Comment: You have a memory leak, you do not `free` loc anywhere at all any more. Why don't you use a local array (`char loc[3];`) instead?

Comment: Optimisation only: a for loop would have been much nicer...

Comment: I disagree on the duplicate; it only covers *one* error, but there are others...

Comment: In my comment above the quote was missing: "If either nelem or elsize is 0, then either a null pointer or a unique pointer value that can be successfully passed to free() shall be returned."

Answer (score 0):

I assume you intended the calloc instruction to allocate 2 characters for the loc pointer. But as pointed out by @Aconcagua, this is not what happens: the second parameter is 0, so effectively 0 memory is allocated!

you probably wanted to do:

```
char *loc=(char*)calloc(2, sizeof(char));
```

This will allocate memory for two consecutive characters. Calloc will by design initialize all allocated memory to zero, so you don't need to do anything for this.

Then you might think that 2 characters is sufficient for the sprintf call that is requested to write a two-digit number into this pointer. However, in C strings are terminated by a null-character and the sprintf-function will add this at the end. Therefore, you would need at least three characters allocated for the loc pointer.

The null-character will now be written into a memory area that may have been assigned to another variable. How exactly this produces the segmentation fault will be very specific to your situation.

So to fix your code, the allocation line should become:

```
char *loc=(char*)calloc(3, sizeof(char));
```

Comment: *'Your calloc instruction allocates 2 characters for the loc pointer'* – no it doesn't, have a close look at second argument... Still nicely spotted not reserving space for the terminating null-character...